# Is it possible to rewrite pykinect2 to be compatible with the Xbox 360 Kinect?

Tags: python, dll, kinect, xbox360, pykinect

I have an Xbox 360 Kinect and want to build a project using it, but I am struggling to get it set up as I know the most up-to-date version of pykinect (Xbox 360) is written for Python 2.7, which I would like not to use, and pykinect2 is written for the Xbox One Kinect as it uses some functions in the kinect20.dll that don't exist in the kinect10.dll (GetDefaultKinectSensor for example).

So, I was mainly wondering if it is possible to rewrite pykinect2 to support the old Xbox 360 Kinect functions or be able to update pykinect to a later Python version. This is my first time ever dipping my toes into rewriting established libraries or dll files to interact with the Kinect API so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes this will be possible, you can use a debuger and port the code/functions needed from the new library into the old library use [ollydbg](https://www.ollydbg.de/) or [ghidra](https://ghidra-sre.org/)